# how to identify the users using the specific cluster in Kusto explorer

Tags: database, azure-devops, cluster-analysis, azure-data-explorer

I was trying to take a list on users using the specific cluster in the kusto explorer.
I dont know how to do this task. Please help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have monitoring permission on the cluster you can use the ".show queries" command to see the activity on the cluster, see more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/queries)

Here is an example:

```
.show queries 
| where StartedOn > ago(1d)
| summarize count() by Database, User
```